# rails - excon gem dependency conflict between mandrill-api & heroku-api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mandrill, excon

I have some dependency conflict since I try to add `mandrill-api`.

I've added the gem in my `gemfile`, but when I want to `bundle install` I've got this error :

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "excon":
 In Gemfile:
mandrill-api (>= 0) ruby depends on
  excon (~> 0.15.4) ruby

heroku-api (>= 0) ruby depends on
  excon (0.13.4)
```

I've tried so many things to fix this, but impossible.
Even if I delete the heroku gems, I still get an error with `fog`.

Anyone has an idea?  thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Looking back it appears you must be using an older version of the mandrill-api gem (more recent ones have a much looser excon requirement). I think if you update to the latest mandrill-gem it should be less problematic and better cooperate with excon/heroku-api/fog. Do let me know if that isn't the case though and I can certainly dig deeper.